# Disable password authentication for making inbound ssh connection only

Tags: macos, security, password, ssh

I have set Remote Login to "on" for my Mac OS X so that I can ssh into it from somewhere else. For security reason, I want to disable password authentication and only allow public key authentication.

I have the following line in /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

> PasswordAuthentication no

However, it also prevents me from login to other servers from my Mac using password authentication:

```
$ sftp username@some_host
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Connection closed
```

I don't have permission to change settings on the `some_host` and have to use password authentication. How can I configure my ssh correctly so that it requires public key authentication for **inbound connection only**, but not the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config (not ssh_config).

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/364304/how-do-i-configure-ssh-on-os-x/993713

Comment: Thanks it works! I think I need to order a pair of glasses : )